# Equivalence between valuations

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, maximal-and-prime-ideals, function-fields

let $k$ be a finite field and $K=k[t]$ be the function field in one variable. Show that a non-trivial, non-Archimedean absolute value $\|\cdot\|$ on K is equivalent to $|\cdot|_{\mathbb{P}}$ for some prime ideal $\mathbb{P}$, generated by a monic irreducible polynomial $p(t) \in k[t]$.

Comment: This is not true.  The absolute value $|f(t)| = 2^{\deg f(t)}$ does not arise in that way.  But the result you ask about *is* true if you avoid this example, the only one (up to equivalence) that is unbounded on $k[t]$. See Theorem 3 and Corollary 4 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/ostrowskiF(T).pdf.